# Android speech recognition keep listening

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I have been trying to modify my voice recognizer application so it would keep listening once started. It would listen up to a silence section and then come back online as soon as the translation is completed.

So I was wondering how this could be possible without having to write a complete API.

I have gone through google and stackoverflow, there is one similar question but no straight answer is given.

If anyone knows to do this, I would be really grateful!

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

[This example app/tutorial](http://androiddev101.com/episode-8-speech-recognition-say-what/) listens for results computes and then starts listening again.  May be what you're looking for.

http://androiddev101.com/episode-8-speech-recognition-say-what/

Comment: @TwistedUmbrella thanks for catching that, I updated the link.

Comment: why you don't post the result here? The link is unavailable now